# Bundle ID Name of app when in the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I sumbmitted an app of mine to the App Store. It has the correct name there which is good but when I download it the name of the app on my home screen is the name of the Bundle ID which is obviously not the proper one. How can I change the name so that it equals the name in the App Store?

Comment: The name shown under the icon is the "Bundle display name".

Comment: In your info.plist change "CFBundleDisplayName" or  "Bundle display name" to same as in appstore as @rmaddy said.You may have to resubmit app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Info.plist` and then change `Bundle name` like below will change app name that will show in home screen.

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect. It is the "Bundle display name", not the "Bundle name" shown to the user below the icon. See the documentation for `CFBundleName` and `CFBundleDisplayName`.

Comment: It depends apps to apps some of my app does not have "Bundle display name" so i used to change "Bundle name", you can see screenshot.